# What is the difference, if any, between these sentences?

Tags: meaning, grammar, sentence

What is the difference, if any, between these sentences?

> Are you having concerns of there could be another attack?
>
> Are you having concerns of there being another attack?

Comment: The first is very poorly written, the second only poorly written.

Comment: Any idea of how to correct them?

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence won't make sense to most English speakers as it doesn't follow conventional rules of grammar.

The second sentence asks if the listener is worried that another attack will occur. However, the following phrasing would be preferable:

> "Are you concerned that there could be another attack?"

This [short article at the BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv183.shtml) has some useful examples of how "concerned" is used. As you can see in the article, "concerns of" is not a common phrase. I would recommend the following:

1) If the object of the sentence is an action that could come to pass, use "concerned that":

> "I am concerned that there will be another attack."
>
> "I am concerned that Donald Trump could become President."

2) If the object of the sentence is a thing or person that could *cause* harm, use "concerned about".

> "I am concerned about the hurricane that is approaching Miami."

3) If the object of the sentence is a thing or person that could *suffer* harm, use "concerned for":

> "I am concerned for my friends in Miami."
>
> "I am concerned for the country now that Donald Trump is President."

Answer (score -1):

The difference is the first setence does not make 'sense'.

You would need to rewrite it like so for it to make sense

> Are you having concerns *if* there could be another attack?

In terms of meaning there is a difference if you do this:-

If your concern is 'if there could be another attack'

You are worried about the possibility of another attack.

If your concern is 'of another attack' your concern is more 'about' the other attack, so could be to do with the repercussions of the attack etc.

Comment: Could I use "Are you having concerns whether there could be another attack?"?

Comment: hmm I would say "Are you having concerns that there will be another attack?" or better still, "Are you concerned that there will be another attack?"

Comment: Do not answer questions which should be closed.